# Send mail with Cron and swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, email, cron

I need to send an email each month so I use a CRON. This one is working but I use symfony and I need to send them with the CRON and the SwiftMailer bundle. What command should I use to execute the mail sending system ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem. I created another symfony command with all my code in the execute function.

Hope this can help someone !

Answer (score 0):

```
please try this method
crontab :

00 12 1 * 0 /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/your_file_name.php
```

Comment: I already tried it and it's not working but I've seen that I need to use this in my crontab 
 : php bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send:

Comment: Mhm ok, I see that it can work with your answer but I cannot test if the mail is ok or not